# Echoing html and $_POST

Tags: php

```
echo "<p id='xlday'>'$_POST['day']'</p>";
```

Hi can anyone help me solve this problem, should be a simple one but i'm struggling for some reason!
Thanks

Comment: This is a horrible security vulnerability. Nothing else. Stop doing what you are doing and read some book or site about XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Alin Do you have the illusion that POST variables can only contain the user's own input??

Comment: @Juliano I would like to see an example. If it's not too much of a bother.

Comment: @Alin Two examples: (1) use CSRF and make the user submit a form from the attackers site (or any other "trusted" site which happened to contain a XSS that allowed the injection of a form), which its "Submit" button styled as a link (yes, you can make buttons look like links using CSS), and targeted to the attacked site. And (2), frame the site inside another site, manipulating it via JavaScript and user trickery. Point (1) is exactly the vuln that plagued even Google-owned sites (orkut and youtube), point (2) is exactly why SO and flickr, among many others aren't allowed to be framed.

Comment: @Alin Don't downplay security, ever. It is exactly because of a mentality like yours (*What's so wrong in showing a user his own input?*) that many sites have the most stupid vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Juliano I'm sorry for my hardheadedness, you are right. I'll try to clear myself of any wrong preconceptions. You example *(1)* I can understand and found some scenarios for it, but could you please explain the second one *(2), frame the site inside another site, manipulating it via JavaScript and user trickery*, maybe with an example?

Comment: @Alin I have just seen it working, but I haven't studied it in detail. Basically the attacked site is put inside an invisible iframe of the attacker site, then use Javascript to move the invisible iframe under the mouse pointer as the user clicks, and also play with focus to capture (and retransmit) keystrokes. See items number 1 and 5 in this page: http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2007/10/24/iframes-security-summary/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo "<p id='xlday'>".$_POST['day']."</p>";
```

Comment: No problem- you can also use echo "<p id='xlday'>",$_POST['day'],"</p>"; its actually faster (by microseconds) in PHP to concatonate with commas as opposed to append.

Comment: This needs `htmlspecialchars()` to protect agains XSS attacks

Comment: @Ergo Summary The `,` does not do any concatenation. It just separates the parameters given to the `echo` construct.

Comment: @Alin, apologies, my bad english

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<p id='xlday'>".$_POST['day']."</p>";
```

or

```
echo "<p id='xlday'>{$_POST['day']}</p>";
```

or

```
echo "<p id='xlday'>${_POST['day']}</p>";
```

or

```
echo "<p id='xlday'>$_POST[day]</p>";
```

I'll also add

```
echo "<p id='xlday'>", $_POST['day'], "</p>";
```

with the mention that it does not actually concatenate the strings, but rather outputs them one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
echo "<p id='xlday'>".$_POST['day']."</p>";
```

Comment: And to elaborate - you had to escape your double quoted sentence with double quotes - you were using single quotes...

Answer (score -1):

You can also do like:

> echo "{$_REQUEST['day']}
>
> ";

However we prefer output buffering.

http://www.suite101.com/content/output-buffer-in-php-a26768

Comment: What does output buffering have to do with this question?